# exit running instance of application using a port and licensing issues in jportable

Tags: java, mysql, wamp, portability

I want to build setup package of a java application that uses mysql as database.
While building the setup, i found some issues

1. User may have already installed java or have older or newer versions.
2. User may have already installed wampserver or mysql or ampps/xammpp or any other application using port 3306.
3. If I start to use same mysql, which user may have already installed, root password may be different.

For the first issue, I thought of using jPortable from PortableApps
For the second and third issue, I am thinking of using some portable instance of mysql too, but the only problem is user may have already installed some application listening to that port and it must be closed.

Now I have two queries:

1. First I dont know if I can openly use java portable in my application and distribute it.
2. Second, I can use net stop wampmysqld and similar commands for other application but is there a generic way to stop any application using this port. Because I dont know what application user may be using blocking the port.

Sorry, if the post is repeated. I tried searching the forum for exiting instances of mysql or application using any port but they all are pointing to unix/linux commands and I am using Windows and assuming user is using windows too. Also, currently I am using wamp server, if thats any help.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sounds like a poor idea. I wouldn't install your software if it insisted on hogging the **default** mysqld port, with no ability to configure things.

Comment: I am newbie and if installer is concerned, this is my first attempt. I rather acknowledge the fact that its not a good idea, but then help me to get to the right way. Firstly, to locally ship a mysql and then changing settings to listen to different port...

Comment: MySQL is a database server, it can server multiple databases. If its already installed why add another instance use the one thats there. I wouldn't necessarily give my root SuperUser password to an installer that could do anything with it, but if you provide instructions to add a database and add a user for that database with all privilages (on that database alone), I would go along with that. As to installing a java version less than current as part of your install, why would anybody want a version of java installed that has already been superceeded because of bugs or vulnerabilities.

Comment: I am assuming system with no pre-requisites. So I have to ship java setup with it. But whatever version I ship, it will become old after few months and then installing automatically the shipped version of java means overwriting newer with old version. Thats why I was using jPortable, so it may not conflict with whatever version user has. The other method is I check what version of Java user already has. If its newer then skip setup of java. But I dont know how to perform this task. Any hint or link will be appreciated. I am complete newbie in building installers and interacting with system.